# Building firefox from source code using WLLVM,received the error 'bad_alloc' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, firefox, compiler-errors, llvm

I'm trying to build firefox using WLLLVM and LLVM 3.8. I receive a set of errors that show there are unrecognized data structures as shown below. I googled this error but couldn't find a solution. Mozilla websites say there is a bug in Firefox, specifically this website https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269171, I manually modified the code according to the provided fix, but still the issue remained. Where I tried to build different versions of Firefox like `40.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0`

```
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:184:33: error: no type named 'bad_alloc' in namespace 'std'
void* operator new(size_t size) MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:175:34: note: expanded from macro 'MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC'
#define MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:172:63: note: expanded from macro 'MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS'
#define MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS throw(std::bad_alloc)
                                                         ~~~~~^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:190:44: error: no type named 'nothrow_t' in namespace 'std'
void* operator new(size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) MOZALLOC_THROW_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
                                      ~~~~~^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:192:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'malloc'
    return malloc_impl(size);
           ^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:61:21: note: expanded from macro 'malloc_impl'
#define malloc_impl malloc
                    ^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:196:35: error: no type named 'bad_alloc' in namespace 'std'
void* operator new[](size_t size) MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:175:34: note: expanded from macro 'MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC'
#define MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:172:63: note: expanded from macro 'MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS'
#define MOZALLOC_THROW_BAD_ALLOC_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS throw(std::bad_alloc)
                                                         ~~~~~^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:202:46: error: no type named 'nothrow_t' in namespace 'std'
void* operator new[](size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) MOZALLOC_THROW_IF_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
                                        ~~~~~^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:204:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'malloc'
    return malloc_impl(size);
           ^
../../../../dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:61:21: note: expanded from macro 'malloc_impl'
#define malloc_impl malloc
```

Comment: Didn't see the code, pure speculation: seems this `mozalloc.h` is just missing some includes. Is it not including <cstdlib> and <new>?

Comment: here is the included files in `mozalloc.h ` 

`
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#  include <new>
#endif
`
It doesn't have  <cstdlib>